# Is there a way to show horizontal and vertical gridlines on a Surface Contour chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

I am creating a chart of type xlSurfaceTopView in VBA. I want the chart to have horizontal and vertical gridlines, but the last two lines of the following With statement only cause two gridlines to appear. Is there a way to show all of them?

```
    With myChart.Chart
        .SetSourceData rng
        .ChartType = xlSurfaceTopView
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Contour Map"
        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(min, 1)
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(max, 1)
        .Axes(xlValue).majorUnit = majorUnit
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True ' from macro recorder
        .Axes(xlSeries).TickLabelSpacing = 1
        .Axes(xlSeries).TickLabelPosition = xlHigh
        .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlHigh
        .Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames = Range("revGridRowHeader")
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesMajor)
        .SetElement (msoElementSeriesAxisGridLinesMajor)
    End With
```

[image: Surface Contour Chart has only one horizontal and one vertical gridline]

Comment: `msoElementSeriesAxisGridLinesMinor` maybe?

Comment: I tried it, but the result is unchanged.